# REALLY SLOW Loop

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

Can anyone give me some insight as to why this takes so long to run? I'm running WinXP on Parallels, with a 16GB MacBook Pro (4 Gigs allocated to the VM). The spreadsheet itself (created by my client) is an absolute nightmare - 38 sheets FULL of ridiculously complicated formulae, and multi-step overly complex algorithms that would make Rube Goldberg quite jealous. But still, this simple routine takes 30 minutes to run.

```
Sub oneList()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ncols = Range("scores").Columns.Count
nrows = Range("sc_id").Rows.Count

'MsgBox nrows, ncols
ReDim Preserve scores(1 To nrows, 1 To ncols)

For i = 2 To nrows
    For j = 1 To ncols
        scores(i, j) = Application.Index(Range("scores"), i, j)
'        Debug.Print i, j
'        Debug.Print scores(i, j)
'        Sheet36.Range("A1:D197").Cells(i - 1, j).Value = scores(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
Sheet36.Range("A1:D197").Clear

For a = 1 To nrows
    For b = 1 To ncols
        Sheet36.Range("A1:D197").Cells(a, b).Value = scores(a, b)
    Next b
Next a

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 3):

You have two for loops, and inside those for loops you change values on the sheet. Every time you change a value the formulas calculate on the front end. Consider stopping the formula auto-calculation with

```
application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

And then at the end of the script turn them back on

```
application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

While they are off you can force a calculation run with

```
application.Calculate
```

Updated:

It looks like most of this is unnecessary as well. You are iterating through a range, assigning each and every cell to a two dimensional array, then iterating through the array and spitting the values back into a different range.

Why not just:

```
Sub oneList()    

    Sheet36.Range("A1:D197").value2 = Range("scores").value2    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I put the manual calculation before the 1st loop, and the automatic after the last. It sped things up a little, but not much. I'm not clear on whether I need to force calculation somehwhere within the loops; I left that out entirely.

Comment: What is Application.index() doing? It looks like you are iterating through rows and columns, assigning them to a two dimensional array, and then pasting that array later on. Why not just skip the iterating and make one range equal to another?

Comment: good catch. but actually, i'm just using this routine as a self-tutorial, on the way to doing something more sophisticated with the array. make sense?

i know, though, because i have split this subroutine into two for testing, that the first half (populate the array) is speedy. the second half (paste the array into a new range) takes about 15 minutes. FIFTEEN MINUTES!!!

Comment: 15 minutes is pretty awful. Is it 15 minutes even with calculations turned off? Any improvements with application.screenupdating off?

Comment: yes, with calculations off, and with screenupdating off. awful. i think it's the spreadsheet itself. reminds me of a sign i once saw in a garage for performance cars. it said "Labor Rates: $50/hour. $75 if you watch, $100 if you help." makes me think i should charge more when clients want to collaborate on the spreadsheet! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can improve performance by populating the destination range in one operation:

```
Sub oneList()

    Dim ncols As Long, nrows As Long
    ncols = Range("scores").Columns.Count
    nrows = Range("sc_id").Rows.Count

    ReDim Preserve scores(1 To nrows, 1 To ncols)

    For i = 2 To nrows
        For j = 1 To ncols
            scores(i, j) = Application.Index(Range("scores"), i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    With Sheet36.Range("A1:D197")
        .Clear
        .Cells(1).Resize(numrows, numcols).Value = scores
    End With

End Sub
```

It's not clear where `scores` array is from, but it's likely you could also re-work your code to populate that in one go from the `scores` range.

Comment: I'm going to try that. thanks. my end goal is actually to populate the multidimensional array with an if-then that checks to see if the cells in the original range meet certain criteria, and then spit the resultant array into a new place in the workbook. (and THEN, sort to remove the blanks where the criteria are not met)

the code i pasted up here is really just a way for me to teach myself how these things work along the way. i'm a bit of a VBA autodidact. and as such, there are many basics i end up having to teach myself on the way to accomplishing the objective of the exercise. :)

Comment: yes, i love this site. usually i just find the answer without having to ask, but this time it was a bit too specific.